# DOM Elements with same id and jQuery

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery

Hi I have multiple elements with the same structure in my application. Second div element's id varies as per the comment id in the db which is unique. There are elements with the id 'vote_up' and 'vote_down'. This gets repeated for each comment.What happens is that, as I mentioned, there are multiple comments. I want to perform an Ajax request. First of this structure functions properly using ajax, but the rest does an http request. Btw I am developing a rails application and I am using jQuery.

```
<div id="post_comment">
john<i> says </i> Comment<br/>

<div id="comment_10_div">
**<form action="/comments/vote_up" id="vote_up" method="post">**
         <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
               <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" 
               value="w873BgYHLxQmadUalzMRUC+1ql4AtP3U7f78dT8x9ho=" />
         </div>
     <input id="Comment_place_id" name="Comment[post_id]" type="hidden" value="3" />
     <input id="Comment_id" name="Comment[id]" type="hidden" value="10" />
     <input id="Comment_user_id" name="Comment[user_id]" type="hidden" value="2" />
     <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Vote up" />
</form>

<label id="comment_10">10</label>

**<form action="/comments/vote_down" id="vote_down" method="post">**
        <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
            <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" 
            value="w873BgYHLxQmadUalzMRUC+1ql4AtP3U7f78dT8x9ho=" />
        </div>
    <input id="Comment_place_id" name="Comment[place_id]" type="hidden" value="3" />

    <input id="Comment_id" name="Comment[id]" type="hidden" value="10" />
    <input id="Comment_user_id" name="Comment[user_id]" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Vote Down" />
</form>
</div>
```

Can you please help me to solve this
Thanks

Comment: Using the same ID twice in the same document is not valid HTML. Fix your HTML.

Comment: You could use the same `class` for the elements with same behavior instead of same `ID`. As already mentioned, `ID`s are supposed to be unique :]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as Matti mentioned above, by the W3C standards ID has to be unique. A nice workaround would be to postfix comment's db ID, e.g. `<input id="Comment_39127438"...`

Comment: It's late that I am commenting on this.  I agree that W3C standards require unique id for each element.  But there may arise cases that id is same for two or more elements, and moreover it does not break the page.

Comment: Those cases with multiple IDs are strongly discouraged. You can tell why if you've built a view in your application that uses Selectors API at any level.

Answer (score 4):

Expanding upon what's already been said, the way you should implement this is:

```
<div id="comment_10" class="comment">
</div>
```

Then you can select all comments with:

```
$('.comment')
```

or a single comment with:

```
$('#comment_10")
```